# 'how come you insist on zoo ticket being included in the contract?' vs 'How com you insist on zoo ticket included in the contract'

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

What's different between 'How come you insist on zoo ticket being included in the contract?' and 'How com you insist on zoo ticket included in the contract?'

I guess that there are some differences between the two sentences depending on 'being', but I can't know what the difference is exactly.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly do you want to know... which is correct? Or why the word 'being' is required?

Comment: The second example is ungrammatical (insist...included).  The first lacks an article, "a zoo ticket".

Answer (score 1):

We can insist *that something be done*.

We can insist *on something being done*.

> She insisted that a zoo ticket be included in the contract.
>
> She insisted on a zoo ticket being included in the contract.

The core meaning is the same.

**Insist that...

Insist on...**

> She insisted that she **have** her own way in this matter.
>
> She insisted on **having** her own way in this matter.

In the *that*-clause version, the verb is not simple indicative ("she has") but is shifted to the bare-infinitive ("she have"), to indicate that the statement does not describe a *present* reality but a *desired* reality. In the first example, "is" shifts to "be". This is a form of *subjunctive* or *irrealis*.

She was not insisting that a zoo ticket was *already* included in the contract; rather, she was expressing a resolute desire that the contract should include a zoo ticket. She *wanted* the contract to include a zoo ticket.